# How do I select a variable row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Frustratingly, I'm working with a table where the row name should be a value. How can I select that row in SQL Server based on a value? I'm aiming at something that looks like this:

```
;with QueryItems as 
(
    select year, model 
    from items
)
select ?QueryItems.model? as Price
from Pricing
where Year = QueryItems.year
```

Items table:

```
item    year      model
------------------------
xx     2001       MODELC
yy     2002       MODELA
zz     2002       MODELD
```

The pricing table is the weird one, set up as:

```
YEAR   MODELA    MODELB    MODELC   MODELD
------------------------------------------
2000   100       101       102      103
2001   205       206       250      300
2002   1000      1200      1500     1700
```

Results I'm aiming for:

```
item   year   model   price   
----------------------------
xx     2001   MODELC   250
yy     2002   MODELA  1000
zz     2002   MODELD  1700
```

Comment: try a dynamic query

Comment: do you need one select for every model?

Comment: I'm looking for a table of results that would return this as part of a larger query.

Comment: its not clear to me, doesn't a inner join between table and pricing do the job=

Comment: I dont see the problem. You can use the `@variable` as a constant and print it. What result you expect?

Comment: I put some sample info in there to show what I'm looking for.

Comment: so looks like `?QueryItems.model?` isnt a variable?

Comment: Right, queryitems.model is where I'm confused. I wanted to get the results in one query or a query/subquery. But it's not a variable from anywhere else. Or a dynamic query but I've no idea what that would look like.

Comment: Can you change pricing table? Looks like you need unpivot first.

Comment: I really wish I could, and making a new table might be what I end up needing to do, but it's not something I created or maintain.

Comment: You need [**unpivot**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) your pricing table, then you can join to your item table.

Comment: Ah, okay I think that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/OMNBD50093)**

use unpivot and then join to your item table.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT [Year], [Model], [Price]
    FROM (SELECT [Year], [MODELA], [MODELB], [MODELC], [MODELD]
          FROM pricing) p
    UNPIVOT 
        ([Price] FOR [Model] IN 
                     ([MODELA], [MODELB], [MODELC], [MODELD])
        ) as unpvt
) 
SELECT i.*, c.price
FROM cte c
JOIN items i 
  ON c.[Year] = i.[Year]
 AND c.[Model] = i.[model]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with standard SQL, albeit a bit ugly:

```
select i.item, 
       i.year, 
       i.model,
       case i.model 
           when 'MODELA' then p.MODELA 
           when 'MODELB' then p.MODELB 
           when 'MODELC' then p.MODELC 
           when 'MODELD' then p.MODELD 
       end as price
from Items i INNER JOIN Pricing p ON p.year = i.year
```

[Rextexter demo](http://rextester.com/LVFHSD26918)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Thank you Juan, that was just a quick attempt; I am not allowed to do such a minor correction though after you have edited my post.

Comment: yes, you can, just reload the page so you have the last version.

Answer (score 1):

What a bad design :( Anyway, you can do what you want in a number of ways and one way is to use UNPIVOT:

```
declare @t1 table (item varchar(10),    year int,      model varchar(10));
insert @t1 (item,year,model) values 
('xx',2001,'MODELC'),
('yy',2002,'MODELA'),
('zz',2002,'MODELD');

declare @t2 table (year int, modela int, modelb int, modelc int, modeld int);

insert @t2 (YEAR,   MODELA,    MODELB,    MODELC,   MODELD) values
(2000,100 ,101 ,102 ,103 ),
(2001,205 ,206 ,250 ,300 ),
(2002,1000,1200,1500,1700);

with up as
( 
  select year, v, model
  from 
  (select YEAR, MODELA, MODELB, MODELC, MODELD from @t2) p
   unpivot  
   (v for model in (MODELA,    MODELB,    MODELC,   MODELD)) as unp
)
select t1.*, up.v from @t1 t1 inner join up on t1.year = up.year and t1.model = up.model;
```