# Prevent duplicates on primary and foreign keys in a self referencing table

Tags: php, mysql

for example:

we have a table `'device'` with `id(primary key)` which references on its self via  `parent_dev_id(foreign key)`.

If you have a device with `{id=1,parent_dev_id=NULL}` and you want to add more devices into it then the next device has id=2 and parent_id=1 or a device `id=2,parent_dev_id=NULL` with 2 devices `id=3,id=4` but they all have the same `parent_dev_id=2`.

Is it possible to deny or restrict certain situations in which id==parent_dev_id? Because we dont want that to be possible

this is the table
[image]

As you can see,the device with `{id=3,parent_dev_id=NULL}` has 2 other devices in it 
eg. device with `{id=4,parent_dev_id=3}` and device `{id=5,parent_dev_id=3}`,its a device inside a device.
Is it possible to restrict `{id!=parent_dev_id}` in the first row where `{id=3,parent_dev_id=NULL}` so that you cant add `{parent_dev_id=3}`.If we do that tt would be an endless loop of devices which reference themselves without any benefit

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your example. Maybe if you post the data like a table, something like [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353860/how-do-i-select-a-variable-row-in-sql-server/42354610#42354610) and explain what is allow and what is forbidden.

Comment: So can you explain again using the sample table? What is ok and what isnt?

Comment: [why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options for solutions that you can do here:

1. Write the logic in your code where the `id` and `parent_id` are not equal
2. Write the logic in the database as a trigger before insert to do the same thing where the `parent_id` and `id` cannot be equal.

The issue that you will run into is if `id` is a generate id. Then it will be tricky to have the situation that you are asking about. On an insert this might be an outlier situation. However, for an update that could be a valid issue where you will want to have for #2 a trigger for an update of the record where the `id` and `parent_id` are not equal.