# PIvot with multiple result values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

im trying to put multiple sums in this pivot table but i havent been succeful,

This is the Raw data
from

```
select 
    billname, 
    orderperiodyear,
    Sum_buyprice,
    Sum_Sellprice,
    Tonnage 
From Sum_Orders
```

[image]

This is my pivot **how can i include buy price and tonnage in the pivot results**

```
SELECT billname,SUM([2017])AS '2017', SUM([2016]) AS '2016'
FROM   Sum_Orders
PIVOT
    (
       SUM(Sum_SellPrice)
            FOR OrderperiodYear IN ([2017],[2016])
     )AS pvt
WHERE  OrderStatus IN ('Complete', 'Invoiced') 
  AND ( (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND day(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE()))
   OR MONTH(OrderDate) < MONTH(GETDATE()))

Group by BILLNAME
HAVING COALESCE(SUM([2017]), SUM([2016])) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY BILLNAME ASC
```

This is what i get from my pivot

[image]

**Im looking for something like this**

[image]

Comment: [why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You have to do unpivot first, and instead of `year` you create values like `year_sell` check this [**example**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42354610/3470178) to get a base query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to skip `pivot()` and go for the old style cross tab.

```
select 
    billname
  , [2016_buyprice]  = sum(case when OrderPeriodYear = 2016 then sum_buyprice else null end)
  , [2017_buyprice]  = sum(case when OrderPeriodYear = 2017 then sum_buyprice else null end)
  , [2016_sellprice] = sum(case when OrderPeriodYear = 2016 then sum_sellprice else null end)
  , [2017_sellprice] = sum(case when OrderPeriodYear = 2017 then sum_sellprice else null end)
  , [2016_tonnage]   = sum(case when OrderPeriodYear = 2016 then tonnage else null end)
  , [2017_tonnage]   = sum(case when OrderPeriodYear = 2017 then tonnage else null end)
from sum_orders 
where OrderStatus in ('Complete', 'Invoiced') 
  and ((month(OrderDate) = month(getdate()) 
    and day(OrderDate) <= day(getdate()))
    or month(OrderDate) < month(getdate()))
group by billname
order by billname asc
```

Comment: This also will give you an idea on how solve it with pivot. instead of  try multi level columns like `{2017, {buy,sell,tonnage}}` you create columns `{2017_buy, 2017_sell, 2017_tonnage}`

Answer (score 2):

You first have to do unpivot first **[DEMO](http://rextester.com/VBMPP94518)**

```
SELECT billname, 
       CAST([OrderperiodYear] as varchar(500)) + '_' + CAST([attribute] as varchar(500)) as attribute,
       [data]
FROM (SELECT billname, 
             [OrderperiodYear],
             [Sum_Buyprice] as Buy,
             [Sum_Sellprice] as Sell,
             [Tonnage] as Ton
      FROM records) p
UNPIVOT 
    ([data] FOR [attribute] IN 
                (Buy, Sell, Ton)
     ) as unpvt
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Then you can create a **[Dynamic Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)**.

Comment: There is an issue with this sample when the value are null. You can solve by using coalesce and convert those to a negative number like -1. http://rextester.com/ZOO68838 or checking any of this [**version**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002989/sql-server-include-null-using-unpivot).